Automate queries in NETEZZA using Azure Data Factory
I have a complex process that occurs monthly and want to automate the process.
I have approximately 10 queries that I manually run in Netezza to output a dataset which can take around 2 days to manually execute.
I want to create a linked service either in ADF or any other service (open to suggestions) and execute the process in a pipeline format
can this be done using any of the current Azure services (functions, logic apps or even DataBricks)?
I can't seem to connect to Netezza and use the query activity to run the code that I need automating, looking for alternative suggestions

This article details the process to integrate Azure data factory with Netezza.  https://medium.com/@johnkarthix/integrate-azure-data-factory-with-netezza-performance-server-on-cloud-d068ce4565a6
Credits to John Gera for the original article.

Not really what I was asking, I'm trying to automate a bunch of scripts that need executing in Netezza but also automated, simply connecting to a dataset and doing a copy activity does not answer the above question
